# I am making a software which has a thread which starts on a button press. But I am not able to stop it even though is is under conditional while loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.9

I am trying to make a Keymapping Software, it has a button which activates the keymapping which basically starts a thread calling a function which has a conditional while loop checking for keypresses.  But the problem is that even though when I am setting the global variable to false using the button, the thread is not killing until I press a key on my keyboard.

this is a little bit frustrating.. as you think that the keymapping is deactivated but then you try to close the software or try to activate another keymapping, it show you error and as soon as you press a key to type something, the cursor clicks on the screen and you get the popup that now your keymapping has been deactivated.....

here's my code.... any suggestions?????

## Keymapping Function

```
def keymapping():
    
    tree.bind('<Return>',func=lambda event=None:())
    
    global active
    global keymapping_running
    global x_cor
    global y_cor
    global start_range
    global end_range
    global selected
    global selected_iid
    global keymap_name
    
    keymapping_running = True
    
    while active:
        
        key = str(keyboard.read_key()).capitalize()
        
        x = int(str(mouse.get_position()).split('(')[1].split(',')[0])
        y = int(str(mouse.get_position()).split(')')[0].split(', ')[1])
                
        for i in saves[start_range+1:end_range+1]:
            i = str(i).split(" = ")
            if i[0] == key:
                x_cor = int(i[1].split(',')[0])
                y_cor = int(i[1].split(',')[1])
        
        if x_cor and y_cor: 
            
            mouse.move(x_cor-x,y_cor-y,absolute=False,duration=0.01)
            mouse.click('left')
    
            x_cor = 0
            y_cor = 0
            
        else:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('F9'):
                button_switch()
            
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('return'):
                
                if keyboard.is_pressed('return'):
                    pass
                
                if tree.selection() == ():
                    pass
                else:
                    app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
                    tmsg.showerror("Already running",f"\'{keymap_name}\' is already running.")
                    app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
            
            else:
                pass
                        
    tree.bind('<Return>',func=lambda event=None:button_switch())

    keymapping_running = False
    x_cor = 0
    y_cor = 0
    selected = ''
    selected_iid = ''
    app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    tmsg.showinfo("Keymapping Deactivated",f"\'{keymap_name}\' has been deactivated")
    app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
    keymap_name = ''
```

## On/Off Button Function

```
def button_switch():
    
    global active
    global keymap_name
    global selected
    global selected_iid
    
    if active:
        tree.item(selected,image=close_img)
        
        active_btn.config(image=on_img)
        active_btn_lbl.config(text='  Activate Keymapping  ')
        active = False
        
    else:
        
        if (not keymapping_running):
            
            if keymap:
                
                selected = tree.focus()
                
                if selected != '':
                    
                    selected_iid = tree.selection()
                    
                    if len(selected_iid) == 1:
                        
                        try:   
                            keymap_name = tree.item(selected,'values')[0]
                            for j in saves:
                                if str(j).split(' :- ')[0] == str(already_keymap_names[int(str(selected_iid).split(",")[0].split("'")[1])]).split(" :- ")[0]:
                                    global start_range
                                    start_range = saves.index(j) 
                                    global end_range
                                    end_range = start_range + int(str(saves[start_range]).split(" :- ")[1].split('(')[1].split(')')[0])     
            
                            active = True 
                            active_btn.config(image=stop_img)
                            tree.item(selected,image=done_img)
                            active_btn_lbl.config(text='Deactivate Keymapping')
                                                   
                            th = threading.Thread(target=keymapping)
                            th.start()
                            
                            tree.selection_remove(tree.focus())
                            
                            app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
                            tmsg.showinfo("Keymapping Activated",f"\'{keymap_name}\' has been activated")
                            app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
                        
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
                            tmsg.showerror("Tampering",f"There has been tampering with the \'Saved_Keymappings.dll\' and we are unable to fetch \'{keymap_name}\'")
                            app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
                    
                    elif len(selected_iid) == 0:
                        app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
                        tmsg.showerror('Nothing selected','Please select a keymapping to activate.')
                        app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
                    
                    else:
                        app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
                        tmsg.showerror("Multiple Selected","You can't run multiple Keymappings together.")
                        app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
                
                else:
                    app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
                    tmsg.showerror('Nothing selected','Please select a keymapping to activate.')
                    app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
            
            else:
                app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
                tmsg.showerror("Nothing to Activate","You have no saved keymappings to activate.\n\nPlaese create a new keymapping before Activating")
                app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
                
        else:
            app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
            tmsg.showerror("Already running",f"\'{keymap_name}\' is already running.")
            app.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what GUI API you are using (is it `tkinter`?), but in most GUI APIs button-handling is done inside the GUI's event loop, which calls callbacks on your code when an event happens, and your callback is expected to return immediately so that the event-loop can contintue handling more events.  So if your callback contains a `while` loop that prevents it from returning immediately, the GUI API's event-handling code is blocked from running, and thus doesn't/can't do the event-handling tasks you expect it to do.

The solution is to make sure your callbacks always return immediately -- in particular, don't do any indefinite-length `while` loops inside your callback; rather set the state of some member-variable(s) in your class to "remember" that you are in the middle of an ongoing event, so that future callbacks can examine those member-variables in order to know to do the right thing.